# htaaccess with parameters and base URL change

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have 2 rewrite rules that I am racking my brain to combine. Basically, I want the following re-write rule where I transform a parameter into the URL string like

The original URL: `https://example.com/?language=english`

The rewritten URL: `https://example.com/english`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?language=$1 [L]
```

I have that covered. Now I am trying to figure out in this rule, how can I change the base URL also from `example.com` to `example2.com`?

This is normally how I change URLs with a 301 redirect..

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite/$1 [R=301]
```

Just not sure how to combine the two? Been experimenting for a while.

EDIT:
I have modified this so there is no need to modify the base URL any longer. So it can be a rewrite.

So my Input URL: http://example.com/redirect/index.php?language=english
and my desired output would be URL: http://example.com/english/

I have placed an .htaacess inside of /redirect directory like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?language=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: "change the base URL" - you mean the "domain". Do these domains point to different servers? And how do you want to "combine these rules"? What is the intended result?

Comment: If you are changing domains then it cannot be internal rewrite.